# Assign shape properties from Excel in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, shapes

I want to assign the properties (Left, Top, Width, Height), which can be defined in the `.AddShape` command, by using Excel.

Now I have assigned the properties directly in the code. The goal is to modify the properties only with data (Left, Top, Width, Height) in the `Excel-Workbook`.

For example, I have a table in Excel with the following data, which changes the shape only by editing the data in Excel:

```
Length: 500    
Top: 200    
Width: 50    
Height: 20
```

My current code looks like this:

```
Sub Text_EAP()

    Dim WB As Workbook, wks As Worksheet


    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="U:\Automatisierung\Auto.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)   
    Set wks = WB.Worksheets("Tabelle1")   '<--- Here is the table with the property data



          Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(51, 607, 195, 70, 15) '<--- The property data here shall be changed accordingly to the Excel-Data
  shp.Name = "Konzentration"
  shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
  shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Konzentration"
  shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = 6
  shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse

   'Exceldatei schliessen
    WB.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

How do I have to change the code that the `shape-properties` will be extracted from data in the `Excel-Workbook`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Something like this will work:**

```
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(wks.Range("A1"), wks.Range("A2"), 195, 70, 15)
```

Change for other Parameters.

---

**Code:**

```
Sub Text_EAP()

    Dim WB As Workbook, wks As Worksheet
    Dim ex As Object

    Set ex = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Set WB = ex.Workbooks.Open(FileName:="U:\Automatisierung\Auto.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
    Set wks = WB.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddShape(wks.Range("A1"), wks.Range("A2"), 195, 70, 15) ' Change all the values & Ranges accordingly

      shp.Name = "Konzentration"
      shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
      shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Konzentration"
      shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = 6
      shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse

    WB.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```